# Given joint moment generating function, what value of $a$ makes $X + 2Y$ and $2X − Y$ independent?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence, moment-generating-functions

I am new to joint moment generating functions and their properties, so am a bit stuck on how to begin the following problem:

Given $M_{X,Y}(t,u) = exp[2t+3u+t^2+atu+2u^2]$, what value of $a$ makes $X + 2Y$ and $2X − Y$ independent?

How should I start working on this problem? I have calculated that $M_X(t)=M_{X,Y}(t,0) = e^{2t+t^2}$ and likewise that $M_Y(u) = M_{X,Y}(0,u) = e^{3u+2u^2}$, but this does not seem to get me anywhere. Can I use the fact that $M_{aX+bY}(\theta) = M_{X+Y}(a\theta,b\theta)$?

Any help with solving this problem would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal. In that case $X+2Y$ and $2X-Y$ is also jointly normal. They are independent iff they are uncorrelated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V=X+2Y$ and $W=2X-Y$. Work out the MGF of $V$ and $W$. This is
$$M_{U,V}(r,s)=E(\exp(rU+sV))=E(\exp((r+2s)X+(2r-s)Y))
=M_{X,Y}(r+2s,2r-s).$$
I'll leave it to you to make the substitution. The aim is to find the $a$ for which
$M_{U,V}(r,s)$ factors in the form $F(r)G(s)$.

Comment: After doing this and simplifying, I get that $M_{U,V}(r,s) = exp[8r+e+9r^2+6s^2-4rs+2ar^2-2as^2+3ars]$. I'm a bit confused on what to do once I'm here.

Comment: Where does the $e$ come from?

Comment: That's a mistake, sorry - it should say: $M_{U,V}(r,s) = exp[8r + s + 9r^2+6s^2-4rs+2ar^2 - 2as^2+3ars]$

Comment: From the above equation, $M_{X+2Y}(r) = M_{U,V}(r,0) = exp[8r+9r^2+2ar^2]$, and $M_{2X-Y}(s) = M_{U,V}(0,s) = exp[s+6s^2-2as^2]$. Then, $M_{U,V}(r,s) = M_{X+2Y}(r)*M_{2X-Y}(s)$ (independence) holds true if $a=0$. Would that be the final answer?

Comment: If $a=0$, you get $\exp(8r + s + 9r^2+6s^2-4rs)$ which doesn't factor as $F(r)G(s)$.

Comment: You're right. Setting $M_{X+2Y}(r)*M_{2X-Y}(s) = M_{U,V}(r,s)$, I see the following equivalence: $8r+9r^2+2ar^2+s+6s^2-2as^2=8r+9r^2+2ar^2+s+6s^2-2as^2-4rs+3ars$, cancelling out to $4rs=3ars$, and $a=4/3$. Would this be correct? Thank you for the help!